# How to take multiple line string input in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++. I want to take multiple line string as input but I can't. I am using `getline()` for it but it is taking only one line input. When I press enter for writing next line it stoped taking input and print the first line.

I want to give input like the example below

```
Hello, I am Satyajit Roy.
I want to make a program.
I love to travel.
```

But it takes only the first line input.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me to know how can I do that.
Thank you.

Comment: How about `while (getline(cin, s)) cout << s << endl;`?

Comment: Do you really have one empty line inbetween at your input?

Comment: `getline` optionally takes a delimiter as parameter. How do you know when input is finished? Is it always 3 lines?

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ No sir, there is no empty line inbetween input.

Comment: @idclev463035818 _"How do you know when input is finished?"_ Well, for `std::cin` it's CTRL-Z (CTRL-D respectively), for file based input it's EOF, no?

Comment: @SatyajitRoy Then [edit] your question please, to make that clearer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this isnt something I ever do in production ( i mean read user input via `cin` or `getline`), but naively I think it is better to use a explicit delimiter instead of relying on CTRL-Z/D

Comment: @idclev463035818 Me neither, but I am pretty sure we're rather talking about homework here, rather than production ready code. Just saying.

Answer (score 3):

Either you write a loop to read individual lines and concatenate them to a single string, thats what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63835140/4117728) suggests. If you are fine with designating a specific character to signal the end of the input, you can use the `getline` overload that takes a delimiter as parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin,s,'x');
    std::cout << s;
}
```

The user would have to type an `x` to end input, so this input

```
Hello, I am Satyajit Roy.
I want to make a program.
I love to travel.
x
```

would result in this output:

```
Hello, I am Satyajit Roy.
I want to make a program.
I love to travel.
```

Of course this won't work when the string to be entered contains `x`, which renders the approach rather useless.

However, instead of using a "real" character as delimiter you can use the `EOF` character (EOF = end of file) like this:

```
 std::getline(std::cin, s, static_cast<char>(EOF));
```

Then input is terminated by whatever your terminal interprets as `EOF`, eg `Ctrl-d` in linux.

Thanks to @darcamo for enlightening me on the `EOF` part.

Comment: You can use the "end of file" as the designated character with `std::getline(std::cin, s, static_cast<char>(EOF));`
EOF is an integer type, usually defined as -1. That is why you need the cast. With that, you can type your multiline string and use whatever key combination your terminal uses for the EOF character when you want to finish entering the string. For instance, you can write your multiline string, type `ENTER` to create an empty line and then type `Ctrl+d` to enter the EOF character (works in Linux). Everything before the last empty line will be captured by `std::getline`

Answer (score 1):

You can only read one line at a time with `std::getline` if you don’t provide your own delimiter. If you want to accumulate multiple lines, one at a time, you need a place to put the result. Define a second string. Read a line at a time into `s` with `std::getline`, and then append `s` to the result string. Like this:

```
std::string result;
std::string s;
while (std::getline(std::cin, s))
    result += s;
```

Comment: @idclev463035818 — yes, I said it too strongly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can take several lines using the code below if you know how many lines you will input.

```
int line=3, t;
string s, bigString;

for(int i=0 ; i<line ; i++)
{
    getline(cin,s); // This is to input the sentence
    bigString += s + "\n";
}

cout << bigString;
```

If you don't know how many lines you will input (Input from file until end of file) then you can check this.

```
string s;
vector<string> all;

while(getline(cin,s))
{
     all.push_back(s);// This is to input the sentence

}

for(auto i:all)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```